# Meaning of spin operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am learning about spin in QM and I was wondering if $\langle{\psi}|\hat{S}_z|\psi\rangle$ where $\psi$ is a spin wave function, is a meaningful quantity? In the case of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$, $\langle\hat{H}\rangle_{\Psi}=\langle{\Psi}|\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle$ is the mean energy for a system with wavefunction $\Psi$, but how should I interpret $\langle{\psi}|\hat{S}_z|\psi\rangle$? Is it something like the average value of $z$ given $\psi$?

I am aware that (spin) $\psi$ lives in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and thus doesn't have "components" in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am also aware that $\hat{S}_n=n_x\hat{s}_x+n_y\hat{S}_y+n_z\hat{S}_z$ is the spin operator in the direction of the unit vector **$n$**, but that this is an operator from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ (just like $\hat{S}_z$), it does not give "components of the spin in $\mathbb{R}^3$". Finally, I know how to use $|n;+\rangle = cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}|+>+sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{i\phi}|-\rangle$, to figure out the spherical angles of any spin, and that will give me $x,y,z$ "components" of the spin (a projection from $\mathbb{C}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$?) - but that seems different from $\langle\psi|\hat{S}_z|\psi\rangle$. (I am also aware that spin operators enter into Dirac's equation, but in my class, we introduced spin and let it sit there in its own $\mathbb{C}^2$ and I must have missed something about $\hat{S}_z:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spin operator $\vec S = \left(\begin{matrix} S_x \\ S_y \\S_z \end{matrix}\right)$ is just like the (orbital) angular momentum operator. $\langle \psi \rvert S_i \lvert \psi \rangle$ gives you the expectation value for the component of the spin angular momentum. $\langle \psi \rvert \vec S \lvert \psi \rangle$ is the expectation for the full spin vector.

The *operators* $S_i$ act on the spin space $\mathbb{C}^2$ just as you say, but their expectation values are real numbers, that, when combined into $\langle \psi \rvert \vec S \lvert \psi \rangle$, are an ordinary vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ - which is then the "spin" part of the total angular momentum expectation for $\psi$.

Comment: Yes - see my other comments - I am just surprised that we were also taught a separate formula for $|n;+\rangle>$ that also gives me $\mathbb{R}^3$ components $x,y,z$ of the spin, albeit via the spherical angles $\theta,\phi$. Am I allowed to use either way to compute a projection of the spin into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (it seems to me we are working with projections from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: @Frank: Yes, the two ways are equivalent. This is not a projection in the strict sense though, just two different ways to get expectation values.

Comment: I thought about "projection" just because the spin is in its own Hermitian 2D space, so it does not have x,y,z components naturally. But you are right - it would be more like a mapping from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ :-)

Comment: @Frank: Careful, what lives in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is not the *spin*, but a *spin state*! Spin itself, i.e. the expectation of $\vec S$, is an ordinary three-vector.

Comment: Hmmm - I thought the "real" object was the "spin" in $\mathbb{C}^2$ ?? After all, doesn't that "spin" thing have properties that we can't account for with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$??

Comment: @Frank: Yes, but you have to distinguish between the strange thing that *has* the spin - the spinor state in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and spin itself, which is just a vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21389/discussion-between-frank-and-acuriousmind).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, your expression is just an expectation value of $\hat{S}_z$ when in the state $| \psi \rangle$. This is an actual measurement you could make on an ensemble of atoms, by running them through a Stern-Gerlach apparatus and counting +$\hbar/2$ for every one that hit the "top" detector and -$-\hbar/2$ for every one that hit the "bottom" detector.

The quantity you've written is a real-valued scalar. It has to be scalar because $\hat{S}_z$ is scalar (that's why it's a component of $\mathbf{S}$) and it has to be real because $\left( \langle \psi | \hat{S}_z | \psi \rangle \right)^* = \langle \psi | \hat{S}_z | \psi \rangle$.

It might be enlightening to you to work this out with a trial spinor (any one you want) and the Pauli matrix $\sigma_z$, which is proportional to $\hat{S}_z$.

Comment: Thanks - I get all that - but what is the meaning of that quantity? Is it the proportion of particles with spin $\hbar/2$?

Comment: As for $\hat{S}_z$, in my class it is $\frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_3$, where $\sigma_3$ is the third Pauli matrix, definitely not a scalar (that's why I was careful to say that $\hat{S}_z$ is a map from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to itself. But I could be wrong here.

Comment: It's sort of the overall spin bias of the particle, yeah. (You could get 0 for instance, which just means that the up and down cancel out in the average I discussed.) But, of course, remember that before you measure, the particle doesn't have one spin or the other, so I'm a little reluctant to say "yes, that many particles have spin +1/2."

Comment: Oh, and I mean that $\hat{S}_z$ is a scalar operator, which was bad wording on my part. Look at this way: bra x ket = scalar. Matrix x ket = ket. So you have bra x (matrix x ket) = bra x ket = scalar.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that spin states live in complex space, however, the expectation value $\left\langle\psi|S_z|\psi\right\rangle$ lives in real space. It is simply a real number, which represents the expectation value of spin if a series of measurements is made in the $z$ direction.

You can see that the expression must be a scalar because $S_z\left|\psi\right\rangle$ just produces some other ket vector, call it $\left|\phi\right\rangle$, so $\left\langle\psi|S_z|\psi\right\rangle=\left\langle\psi|\phi\right\rangle$, which is clearly a scalar value.

Comment: Yes, no problem here, it is a scalar, real measurement - but if it is the expectation value of the spin in the $z$-direction, why do we bother with the expression I put there about $|n;+\rangle$?

Comment: That expression allows you to determine the probability amplitudes in the spin z up and z down directions for any given measurement direction, but it's not exactly the same as an expectation value. If you want the expectation value of spin in the z direction given some state $\left|+n\right\rangle$ given by the formula, then you need to evaluate $\left\langle+n|S_z|+n\right\rangle$

Comment: But, with the 3 $\hat{S}_i$ I can get 3 values, and they are indexed by $x,y,z$, so I was thinking I would get "expected values of $x,y,z$-components of the spin", and lo and behold, I just completed an exercise where some arbitrary spin was reduced to $x,y,z$ components via the $|+n\rangle$ formula... hence my initial question. Would the values of $x,y,z$ be numerically different between the 2 computations?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simple example, a free electron in a magnetic field $H$, and let's take for simplicity the direction $z$ in the direction of the field. The electron has a magnetic dipole, $\vec {\mu}$. In Stern-Gerlach experiments we find this dipole either oriented in the direction of the field, or oppositely. We say, accordingly, that the projection of the ***spin*** of the electron on the direction of the field ($z$) is spin-up, or spin-down, and the corresponding eigenvalues are $hbar /2$ and $-\hbar /2$.

This is, 1st of all, the meaning of the eigenstates of the operator $\hat S_z$. We can use for them the simple symbols $|\uparrow\rangle$ for spin-up state, and $|\downarrow\rangle$ for the spin-down state, but in calculi with the Pauli matrixes, more useful are the forms

$$|\uparrow\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} {1} \\ {0} \end{bmatrix} \ \text {and} \  |\downarrow\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} {0} \\ {1} \end{bmatrix}\tag{i}.$$

**However**, if the electron enters the field in an eigenstate of another spin projection operator, $\hat S_n$, that say, makes an angle $\theta$ with the field $\vec H$, that state can be represented, as a superposition of the eigenstates of $\hat S_z$, i.e.

$$\psi = cos(\theta /2)|\uparrow> + sin(\theta /2)|\downarrow⟩, \tag{ii}$$

or,

$$|\psi\rangle = cos(\theta /2) \begin{bmatrix} {1} \\ {0} \end{bmatrix} + sin(\theta /2) \begin{bmatrix} {0} \\ {1} \end{bmatrix}\tag{iii}.$$

The value $\langle\psi|S_z|\psi\rangle$ of which you ask, will be the mean value of $\hat S_z$, in this state. To understand that one can make  Stern-Gerlach experiment. It will give you the response "spin-up", i.e. $\hbar /2$ in $cos^2(\theta /2)$ cases and "spin-down" i.e. $-\hbar /2$ in $sin^2(\theta /2)$ cases, s.t. the mean value will be $<\psi|\hat S_z|\psi> = cos^2(\theta/2) - sin^2(\theta/2) = cos\theta$.

**Remark** : you say *""* and that will give me x,y,z  "components" of the spin (a projection from $\mathbb{C}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$? **No**, there is nothing to do here with $\mathbb{R}^3$. If the electron has a *well-defined* spin-direction, e.g. the direction $x$, then the values of $S_z$ and $S_y$ are undefined.